# バッチファイルでPythonのソースコードの行数をカウントしたい。

Tags: batch-file

Pythonで作成したソースコードのステップ数を数えるため、空行を除く行数をカウントしたいと考えています。
複数のフォルダにソースコードがあるため、以下のようなバッチを作成しました。

```
@echo off

for /r %~dp0 /f "delims=" %%a in (*.py) do (
  find /c /v "" %%a >> pycount_result.csv   
)
```

しかし、デリミタ"delims="の記述が違反していると返ってきて、実行できません。
どのように記述したらよいか、ご存知の方はご教示をお願いします。

実行環境：Windows10Pro

また、コメント行（#で始まる行）も取り除く方法もあれば、ご教示をお願いします。

Comment: バッチファイルで実行するのは必須条件ですか?

Comment: Pythonコードの行数はPythonで数えるのが適切ではないでしょうか…？

Comment: 特にバッチファイルで実行する必要はないのですが、何か良い方法がありますでしょうか？

Comment: このあたりでしょうか。[pygount](https://pypi.org/project/pygount/), [metrics](https://pypi.org/project/metrics/), [SourceMeter](https://www.sourcemeter.com/)

Comment: 更なる機能も含めた品質管理ツール類が紹介されてましたので。[Code Metrics - Full Stack Python](https://www.fullstackpython.com/code-metrics.html)

Comment: metricsを試してみました。しかし、下記の回答方法を試したのと同じように、globモジュールが次のような例外エラーを出しているようです。

Comment: File "c: \ program files (x86) \ microsoft visual studio \ shared \ python36_64 \ lib \ site-packages \ pathlib2 \ __ init__.py", line 1360, in glob
raise NotImplementedError ("Non-relative patterns are unsupported")
NotImplementedError: Non-relative patterns are unsupported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

openのオプションを追加すれば解決しました。ありがとうございました。

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import glob

for f in glob.glob(r".\**\*.py", recursive=True):
    c = sum([1 for l in open(f,encoding="utf-8_sig") if not l.strip().startswith("#")])
    print('{}: {} lines'.format(f, c))
```

Answer (score 1):

バッチファイルでエラーが発生する理由は、`/r`で再帰的にファイルを取得するコードと`/f`でファイルの中身を読み込むコードか混在しているためです。

下記のサンプルコードのように多重ループでファイルを読み込むよう改修することで、エラーを発生させずに再帰的にファイルの行数を取得することができます。

**count.bat**

```
@echo off

rem 遅延評価することでecho !c!を有効にしている
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem 再帰的にpythonファイルを取得して%fに代入
for /r %~dp0 %%f in (*.py) do (
  rem 単純に各行を読み込んで行数を出力する
  set c=0
  for /f "delims=" %%a in (%%f) do (
    set /a c=c+1
  )
  echo !c!
  rem コメントが存在しない行をカウントする(質問の意図は満たしていない)
  find /c /V "#" %%f
)
```

しかし上記の方法ではコメント行を削除する処理ができていません。
(`find /c /V "#" %%f`では、末尾コメントを含めてコメントのある行を除外してしまいます)
python 3.5 以降ならば下記のコードで行コメントを除く行数を取得できます。

**count.py**

```py
import glob

for f in glob.glob(r".\**\*.py", recursive=True):
    c = sum([1 for l in open(f) if not l.strip().startswith("#")])
    print('{}: {} lines'.format(f, c))
```

この処理で行コメントは除外してカウントできますが、複数行のブロックコメントを除外できません。
そのため @kunif さんが示されているようにpythonと外部のプラグインを併用することをお勧めいたします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。アドバイスいただいた方法をいくつか試してみて、今後使用していく方法を決めたいと思います。

Comment: Windows環境では、globは使えないという理解で正しいでしょうか？

Comment: globはWindows環境でも使えます。(回答のサンプルコードはWindows10で動作確認済みです)python 3.5より前のバージョンでは使えませんのでバージョンをご確認ください。

Comment: バージョンは、3.6.5のようです。
例外が発生しました: UnicodeDecodeError
'cp932' codec can't decode byte 0x88 in position 1881: illegal multibyte sequence
  File "C:\Users\Funahashi\Documents\vs_code_python\ImagenicsBlueriverControl\TestProgSteps.py", line 4, in <listcomp>
    c = sum([1 for l in open(f) if not l.strip().startswith("#")])
  File "C:\Users\Funahashi\Documents\vs_code_python\ImagenicsBlueriverControl\TestProgSteps.py", line 4, in <module>
    c = sum([1 for l in open(f) if not l.strip().startswith("#")])

Comment: 上記のような例外エラーで、デコードエラーが発生しています。